# Load Balancing Sort Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, load, load-balancing

Im working on a program that sets the affinity for a process. I have pre-determined data that allowed me to calculate the rough percent of a CPU (or core) that a process uses during each of the three stages of the programs life. Every process has these same three stages, and I have pre-determined data for each process in each of these three stages. I am trying to determine the best algorithm that can sort the processes. The kicker is I cant sort each stage individually. For process X, all three stages have to be taken into account when being compared against process Y in the algorithm. As an example with some made up data:

```
    CPU's currently at the following loads:

    CPU | Stage 1 | Stage 2 | Stage 3
    ---------------------------------
    1   | 25%     | 25%     | 25%
    2   | 50%     | 50%     | 50%
    3   | 75%     | 25%     | 75%
    4   | 50%     | 25%     | 10%

    Process X was pre-determined to take up 
    10% in stage 1, 20% in stage 2, and 30% in stage 3.
```

What I have come up with so far is to add the pre-determined percent that process X takes up to each CPU, which would result in this:

```
    CPU | Stage 1 | Stage 2 | Stage 3
    ---------------------------------
    1   | 35%     | 45%     | 55%
    2   | 60%     | 70%     | 80%
    3   | 85%     | 45%     | 105%
    4   | 60%     | 45%     | 40%
```

and rank each CPU's stage against the other (giving ties the same value), which would result in this:

```
    CPU | Stage 1 | Stage 2 | Stage 3
    ---------------------------------
    1   | Rank 1  | Rank 1  | Rank 2
    2   | Rank 2  | Rank 2  | Rank 3
    3   | Rank 3  | Rank 1  | Rank 4
    4   | Rank 2  | Rank 1  | Rank 1
```

and then weight the rankings by the how much each process uses at each stage, and adding the final rank * weights across each stage to get a integer to determine which CPU assignment is best. In this example I would give stage 3, a weight of 3 because it is the highest value stage for this process, stage 2 a weight of 2 and stage 1 a weight of 1 for the same reason as stage 3. This would result in:

```
    CPU | Stage 1 | Stage 2 | Stage 3 | Sum
    -----------------------------------------
    1   | 1       | 2       | 6       | 9
    2   | 2       | 4       | 9       | 15
    3   | 3       | 2       | 12      | 17
    4   | 2       | 2       | 3       | 7
```

Since CPU 4 has the lowest sum, it is therefore the best canidate to assign Process X to. There still are a few kinks in this I believe, and I think there could be a much better way of doing it (which is why I am asking you!). I just thought I would explain what I have so far, just to give you an idea of what I am working with.

Edit: I should add that you cant simply sum the stages for each CPU and then apply a sorting algorithm. Each stage must stay under 100%, and if you sum the stages, you could inadvertently assign a process to a CPU that does not have room for it. IE, assigning process Y with 90%/20%/30% was calculated (under the assumption of summing the stages) to be assigned to CPU 1 with 20%/30%/40%. The sum of the stages for this CPU could be less then any other CPU, but adding stage 1 of process Y (90%) to stage 1 of CPU 1 (20%) is greather then 100%, and would result in an overrun.

Summing the stages should be avoided anywhere because it hides possible problems.

What I believe this really boils down to is... How do you sort data sets? Since each CPU is essentially a data set (stage 1, stage 2, stage 3) that I need to sort in order to determine the process assignment.

Edit 2: I just ended up going with my description here.

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying you want to sort PROCESSES so that you can schedule as many of them as possible to run under the current balance load of CPUs?

This is just like a 01-[knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) problem, except there are three dimensions (stages) instead of two (size, weight). I suppose the solutions for Knapsack (dynamic programming or greedy) will also work for you.